# Adding different number of '-' in every loop (javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, loops, numbers, iteration

I need to create a string like this: `01-2--3---4----5-----6------7-------` for a let n=7, using a loop.
I've created something like this so far:

```
let numbers = '';
n = 7;

for(i=0; i<=n; i++) {
numbers += i;
if (i>0) {
numbers += ('-')
}}
```

which gives me: "01-2-3-4-5-6-7-". Don't know how to change the code so that it could multiply the number of '-' equal n in every loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a nested loop, to iterate over the value of `i` in the outer loop.

```js
const n = 7
let result=''
for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
  let dashes=''
  for(let j=0; j < i; j++){
      dashes+='-'
  }
  result+= `${i}${dashes}`
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) for the wanted dash.

Do not forget to declare **any** variable.

```js
let numbers = '',
    n = 7;

for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) numbers += i + '-'.repeat(i);

console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

This the solution for your problem:

```
var numbers = '';
var n = 7;
for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
numbers += i;
    for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    numbers += "-";
   }
}
```